# Hide table when there is no visible row using knockout

Tags: knockout.js, html-table, hide, rows

I have a table for which the rows visibility is handled by item type selection in the dropdown list. following is my code (I have used knockout.js).

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.elements">
     <tr data-bind="visible:$root.selectedType==elementType">
       <td>
         <span data-bind="text:elementValue"></span>
      </td>
     <tr>
  </tbody>    
</table>
```

Here the `$root.selectedType`'s value is changed on the dropdown's selection. Sometimes there is a case when there is no element for the selected type and in that case I have an empty table (only headers are displayed). My requirement is to hide the table when there is no element(rows) for the selected type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `visible` binding:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" 
       data-bind="visible: $root.elements().length > 0">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.elements">
     <tr data-bind="visible:$root.selectedType==elementType">
       <td>
         <span data-bind="text:elementValue"></span>
      </td>
     <tr>
  </tbody>    
</table>
```

This will show the table if `$root.elements` has a non-zero length

Comment: Probably need `$root.elements().length`, since `length` is not a property of an `observableArray`.

Comment: true, but OP never mentioned what was observable, updating to make that assumption

Comment: Actually, your safest bet: `ko.unwrap($root.elements).length`